# No such file or directory on js script

Tags: node.js, linux, cron

[This is the code used to open the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQjVk.png)

[The function used in code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpfXj.png)

I have a crontab that run an script with the following command:
usr/bin/node /services/integration/build/index.js

The cron log generates the following error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './sql/search.sql'

My project folder structure:
integration/
build/
sql/
src/

If I access my project folder and run node build/index.js, it works properly, what should I do o solve this issue?

I have already tried to move the sql folder

Comment: Show the code that tries to open `'./sql/search.sql'`

Comment: The working directory is not what you think when running from cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the working directory of your process is not the project directory, but `$HOME`. `.` is relative to the working directory. You have to either use a path relative to the script file or change the working directory with `cd` before running your script. See also [this question on the Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job).

From how you described your setup and paths in the question, I assume the project directory is `/services/integration`, and the script has a relative path of `build/index.js` and is trying to access `/services/integration/sql/search.sql`. In this case:

**To specify a path relative to the script file:**

```js
import { dirname, resolve } from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

// Get equivalent of __dirname but within ESM
// This will contain `/services/integration/build`, assuming script file in "build" directory
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

// Get correct path for SQL file
const sqlFilename = resolve(__dirname, '../sql/search.sql')
```

-- OR --

**To change the working directory with `cd`:**

Code in crontab (assuming correct project path is `/services/integration`):

```
cd /services/integration && /usr/bin/node build/index.js
```